# getting a user input description for every item in a list

Tags: python, list, loops

I want to have my users input a short description of every item in a list that they input the length of.

like this output:

```
how many items do you want to sell?: 4 (this should be a number between 1 and 25)

enter the name of every item:
1:
2:
3:
4:

(again this list will be determined by what the user inputs at the first question)

enter the price of every item:
name of 1:
name of 2:
name of 3:
name of 4:
```

my code so far looks like this:

```
amount = int(input("enter the amount of items you want to sell: "))

while 1 > amount > 25:
    print("Error the number should be between 1 and 25.")
    amount = int(input("enter the amount of items you want to sell: "))

names = []
prices = []
```

I use lists because that is what is requested of me for the project I am working on.

Comment: `1 > aantal > 25` can never be true. It should be `1 < aantal < 25`

Comment: You never update `aantal` in the loop, so it will be an infinite loop.

Comment: I guess `aantal` should be `amount`, or vice versa.

Comment: And use `<=` if you want to allow `1` and `25`.

Comment: yes I edited it. so I am editing my loop in my code too

Comment: So what problem are you having? Loop `amount` times, in each iteration ask for a name and price, and append them to the appropriate lists.

Comment: Yes so my first loop is working now thanks. I understand the concept of appending it's just that I still have some difficulties in coding it so it will look like the preferred output

Comment: Show what you tried and we'll help you fix it. We don't do your homework for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use for loops in cases that you know the length of loop:

```py
amount = int(input('how many items do you want to sell?: '))

item_names = []
item_prices = []

print('enter the name of every item:')
for i in range(1,amount+1):
    item_names.append(input(f'{i}: '))

print('enter the price of every item:')
for i in item_names:
    item_prices.append(input(f'{i}: ')) #you can convert to int or float before appending, if that's what you want
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution which will take inputs in range between 1 to 25(both excluded). To include, replace `>` with `>=` and `<` with `<=`

```
import sys
amount = int(input("enter the amount of items you want to sell: "))
names=[]

if amount>25 or amount<1:
    sys.exit("Invalid Input")
    
print('enter the name of every item:')
for i in range(amount):
    name = input(str(i+1)+': ')
    names.append(name)
    
print('enter the price of every item:')
for name in names:
    input(name+': ')
```